# angularjs - md-grid-list with YouTube Style Slide?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Is it possible to use [this](https://i.imgur.com/G6AQELU.gifv) style slider with md-grid-list?
Of course also allowing to scroll back.

What I have tried is to use a specified height with a Container div (To make it 1 line), but it only gives me a Y scrollbar which is expected, but how can I make it give me a horizontal scrollbar or just somehow make it work like youtube's?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score -1):

Did you checked [slick-carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/#settings) ?

On the demos tab, there's a really cool example on a similar output that you look for (called Responsive Display). And it's possible to use it with ***md-grid-list***. Its quite simple to put it to use and it might be helpful on other situations.

Comment: Looks like it yes, but do you know how to implement md-grid-list into it? im having a hard time getting it to work.

Comment: You mentioned on the Demos tab about "Responsive Display" but I cant find anything related to it.